# How to override docker ignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, docker, docker-compose

I have dockerfile and dockerignore files in the project root folder. these two are used to build docker image and deploy it to the prod.
I have another dockerfile in my spec which will build the docker image to run integration tests.

Issue:
spec folder is added in dockerignore. But I need spec folder for my integration tests docker image. How to override docker ignore?

Is it possible to copy dockerignore files manually by doing something in dockerfile
Is there a way that I can add one more dockerignore specifically to use for my integration tests.

Comment: Just remove the spec directory from the dockerignore file.

Comment: There no clean way to use multiple dockerignores, I believe. My solution was to use one Dockerfile, copy everything but spec, add a LABEL, copy spec, add another LABEL. My pipeline would grab the tagged labels and push those images/layers up for the respective new images. Multistage builds might be an option now also